# NLog: Logger instance specific variable (correlation ID)

Tags: correlation, nlog

I have a long business process.
Multiple process instances can run simultaneously.
I create a logger at the start of this process and pass it through the whole process. This is necessary to connect all the actions of this process into a single chain.
Does the logger have something like a correlation ID or is it possible to define a logger level variable to write it to the database as a correlation ID.

Comment: I assume C#, is that correct?

Comment: Maybe use `Logger.WithProperty`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer#logger-withproperty-or-setproperty

Answer (score 0):

What about using the MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext?

```cs
using (NLog.MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped("corelationId", MyCorelationId))
{
    Logger.Info("Hello");
}
```

In your config: `${mdlc:item=corelationId}`

There are more context classes, see [NLog custom context](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Context)